# async function re-entering without being called

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, pdf.js

This is most probably due to my limited experience with JavaScript, but I haven't been able to figure this out. This is a Vue 2 + Typescript project, but the specific problem doesn't have anything to do with Vue or Typescript.

OK. So I have added the following functions in one of my components. Primary purpose of this component is to take a PDF file and return the rasterized version of its first page in the form of a `Blob`. Here are my functions:

```
async importButtonHandler () {
  if (this.file) {
    const blob = await this.pdfToBlob(this.file)
    if (blob) {
      const file2 = new File([blob], 'raster_pdf', { type: 'image/png' })
      // Further processing
    }
  }
}

async pdfToBlob (pdfFile: File): Promise<Blob|null> {
  const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas')
  const buffer = await this.readFileAsync(pdfFile)
  const typedarray = new Uint8Array(buffer)

  // get handle of pdf document
  const doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(typedarray).promise

  // get handle of page
  const pdfpage = await doc.getPage(1)

  // get viewport to render the page at required scale
  const viewport = pdfpage.getViewport()

  // set canvas height same as viewport height
  canvas.height = viewport.height
  canvas.width = viewport.width

  const renderContext: RenderParameters = {
    canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D,
    viewport: viewport
  }

  // render the page contents in the canvas
  await pdfpage.render(renderContext).promise

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      canvas.toBlob(resolve)
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error)
    }
  })
}

readFileAsync (file: File): Promise<ArrayBuffer> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload = () => {
      resolve(reader.result as ArrayBuffer)
    }

    reader.onerror = reject

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
  })
}
```

It hits the function `pdfToBlob` and calls `readFileAsync` from therein, reads the file into `buffer` correctly, but immediately after that (on `const typedarray = new Uint8Array(buffer)`) instead of executing that line, it hits `pdfToBlob` function again and then throws an exception saying:

> `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDocument')`

and for the life of me I can't figure out why it enters the function again (there is no other place where this function is called).

My gut feeling is that it is about the Promise that I'm returning in the function, but all my experimentation hasn't led me to any clue.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong here?

Comment: How are you calling `importButtonHandler()`.  It seems to me that you may be calling that function more than once without waiting for the prior call to complete.

Comment: Also, that specific error you get makes it seems like `pdfjsLib` is `undefined`.  Where does that variable come from?

Comment: @jfriend00: I just figured that out to be the case. But I cannot see how I'm calling it twice. The string `importButtonHandler` appears only twice in the entire source. One is the function signature itself and other is the click event binding of my front-end button, `<v-btn @click="importButtonHandler" />`.

Comment: @jfriend00: `pdfjsLib` is simply the following import: `import pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist'`

Comment: I don't know what `<v-btn @click="importButtonHandler" />` is.  Perhaps you could show the actual generated HTML/Javascript that the browser sees.

Comment: `<v-btn>` is a Vue component. The output HTML is quite convoluted. Even though the generated HTML element is a button, It doesn't have any `onclick` in the tag. Looks like Vue is adding event listener dynamically. In any case, collecting all those shredded pieces of JS is not easy.

Comment: Well, somehow you're going to have to track down why your function is getting called twice.  I don't know how else to do it other than go backwards in the generated Javascript and find out where the call to `importButtonHandler()` comes from.  I don't know vue.js, but are you required to call some form of `preventDefault()` to stop propagation to some higher level that could cause a problem?

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks for the input. It really was about adding a `preventDefault` kind of thing (in Vue's way). I also found that this annoying behavior has already been reported. So the two calls issue seems to be fixed, but the other one (pdfjsLib undefined) is still there. I'll keep digging.

Comment: So, is there more to your question here that you want us to try to help with?  If `pdfjsLib` is `undefined`, you just need to trace back how/where that happened.  That doesn't appear to be in any of the code you show here.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for the input. I understand what a PDF is and how PNG is different from it. The sole purpose of `pdf.js` library that I have used above is to convert PDF file to image format. I have solved my problem now. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out (kind of).

Firstly, my `pdfjsLib` needed to be imported correctly and supplied with a *worker* before calling `getDocument`. This was the cause of my second issue. Here is the correct way of importing the lib and worker in Vue 2/Typescript project:

```
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist'
import pdfjsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry'
```

Then supply worker to the library and call getDocument:

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker
const doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(YOUR_PDF_DATA).promise
```

Rest of the code in my OP works correctly. Note that `pdf.worker.entry` doesn't have type definitions (or at least I couldn't find them anywhere), but it works nonetheless.

The first issue of getting handler called multiple times seems to be a known issue (or behavior if you like) in Vuetify. They suggest to use `native`, or `prevent` or `stop` when defining the `click` attribute (like `@click.stop="importButtonHandler"`) to mitigate the behavior. I have tried it without success. My handler is still called twice. In my particular scenario this doesn't cause any functional harm so I can live with it for now, but I can think of situations where this behavior could be disastrous.

Hope this helps someone down the road.